# Reverse Engineering CHALLENGE

Tags: firmware, binary

I have a BIN firmware archive file starts with `04 02` which is unknown to me
what makes me sure it is an archive file is the source I got it from

BINWALK and all other known tools failed to identify single information from the file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Update files usual even when are not encrypted have missing bootloader section. What is your file source? You know which architecture of mcu is used there?

Comment: If looking at the first two bytes without knowing anything else about the device, the firmware file or its source, `binwalk` or one of the other tools you tried would have identified the format. To make use of the crowd knowledge on Stack Exchange, you need to add a lot of extra information we humans can make better use of than a computer. If legally and technically possible, provide a copy of the file, and a short explanation of the device it is intended to be used on.

Comment: The typical things for "archive of some kind" are words (32 bit or even 64 bits) that contain member lengths and possibly also file offsets. Depending on the archive type, there are also identifiers for the members like a name or ID numbers. Archives tend to have these member information records at the file begin, the end or in front of each member. If you are working on a challenge, I guess you job is to manually identify the archive structure